# Msbuild Exec Command should execute based on ASP .Net Core's appsettings.json or launchSetting.json file

Tags: .net, npm, msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0

We have a project in the ASP .Net Core in that we have implemented the GULP task in the .csproj file with below command it is executed very well. on every build

Command

```
<Target Name="PreBuild" AfterTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="npm run create-bundles" />
</Target>
```

Because of some reason we need to run this command based on LanchSettings's properties value or appsettings.json properties value

OR

If you have any other solution then also tell me.

Thanks